# ReplayingDecoder throws exception on decode

Tags: java, netty, nio

I have created an decoder to process bytes that client sends. 
Here is it

```
import java.util.List;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder;

public class MessageDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<DecoderState> {

    private int length;

    public MessageDecoder()
    {
        super(DecoderState.READ_LENGTH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf, List<Object> out) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(buf.readableBytes());
        switch(state()){
            case READ_LENGTH:
                length=buf.readInt();
                System.out.println("length is: "+length);
                checkpoint(DecoderState.READ_CONTENT);
            case READ_CONTENT:
                ByteBuf frame = buf.readBytes(length);
                checkpoint(DecoderState.READ_LENGTH);
                out.add(frame);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error("Shouldn't reach here");
        }
    }
}
```

And it throws next error when the client sends the bytes

> io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: minimumReadableBytes: -603652096 (expected: >= 0)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:431)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:245)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:962)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

That code is from official documentation http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html  so i really don't understand why it does not work

Comment: btw when I send 4 bytes it says me that I sent 2147483647 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Probably the remote peer does write the int as unsigned. Maybe what you want is using readUnsignedInt() ?

Comment: but it has 'long' type, and it's 8 bytes don't it? the remote peer writes 4 bytes

Comment: without seeing what exactly the remote peer does its hard to tell. What I can tell you is that readInt() returns a negative number here.

Comment: my remote peer just sends an integer value, 4 bytes http://pastebin.com/NGmqK5PH but Netty says that 2147483647 bytes are available when I use System.out.println(buf.readableBytes());

Comment: thats because you use ReplayingDecoder which will always return Integer.MAX_VALUE if not terminated yet.

Maybe your remote system uses different endianness ? You can see if this is true by using in.readIntLE()